# Quick way to add the signature of an inherited method using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I know there is a feature "Add unimplemented methods" in case one implements a Java interface. I would like to know if there is a way to select a couple of the inherited methods and generate their signatures automatically as in the previously mentioned case.
I have to mention that I'm using Eclipse Helios for Java.

Comment: Do you mean when you just extend a class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, here's how:

*Right click* -> *Source* -> *Override/Implement Methods*

[image]

Comment: Default shortcut is fun to use too: Alt+Shift+S, V

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what [aioobe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416975/quick-way-to-add-the-signature-of-an-inherited-method-using-eclipse/6416992#6416992) said, you can take advantage of a feature called *code completion*. Simply hold *Ctrl+Space* and a menu will appear with methods you may wish to override. Depending on what you are doing, this could be faster than the other solution mentioned.